# Howto extract a complete DOM Tree out of an HTML Page

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom, computed-style

I have to comparare two web pages and analyse if there is any difference between them. 
The problem is: i need to include every DOM element (also the ones that are added dynamically through javascript), AND i need to include all applied CSS settings (aka. computed style).

For example: if there is an CSS `:hover` setting defined, I need to get a different result when my mouse  is over the element, than when it is not over the  element.

Maybe I could make an javascript iteration through every element of the page, ask for every css setting and for every child DOM element. But i think this would take a long time and would blow the resulting DOM and make it more difficult to compare.

Any ideas?? Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

For Firefox, [XmlSerializer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XMLSerializer) is your friend.

Comment: Looks good - but here the computed style is NOT part of the serialisation!?

Answer (score 0):

I would check out selenium. There is a command selenium.getHtmlSource(); You can call this after a javascript function occurs. After a quick look I found this

http://davidlaing.com/2008/12/29/selenium-gotcha-seleniumgethtmlsource-returns-processed-html/

and

[Need to compare 2 html documents using Java & selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3242640/need-to-compare-2-html-documents-using-java-selenium)

I am sure its not the elegant way you were hoping for but I hope this will get you started

Comment: getHtmlSource() gets you the original HTML, not the dynamically modified current page.  There are some very minor alterations, as the DavidLaing.com article says, but nothing significant.