# HTML differences for track-change like implementation

Tags: html, node.js, python-3.x

I am attempting to implement a Google Docs-like version history which track changes of the document. My inputs are HTML code, both before and after the change. I have read posts from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3366332/6792327) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35462688/6792327) but realised that they are ideal for identifying differences between the source code, ie HTML tags are simply read as plain text.

Here is an example:

```
//Before
<ol>
    <li><strong>This is first bullet point</strong>
        <ol style="list-style-type: lower-alpha;">
            <li>First bullet - sub a</li>
            <li>First bullet - sub b</li>
        </ol>
    </li>

    <li><strong>This is second bullet point</strong>
        <ol style="list-style-type: lower-alpha;">
            <li>Second bullet - sub a
                <ol style="list-style-type: lower-roman;">
                    <li>Point 1</li>
                    <li>Point 2</li>
                </ol>
            </li>
            <li>Second bullet - sub b</li>
            <li>Second bullet - sub c</li>
        </ol>
    </li>
</ol>

//After
<ol>
    <li><strong>This is first bullet point</strong>
        <ol style="list-style-type: lower-alpha;">
            <li>First bullet - sub a with extended content</li>
            <li>Edited bullet - sub b</li>
        </ol>
    </li>

    <li><strong>This is second bullet point</strong>
        <ol style="list-style-type: lower-alpha;">
            <li><u>Second bullet - sub a</u>
                <ol style="list-style-type: lower-roman;">
                    <li>Point 1</li>
                    <li>Point 2</li>
                    <li>Point 3</li>
                </ol>
            </li>
            <li>Second bullet - sub b</li>
            <li>Newly inserted bullet</li>
            <li>Second bullet - sub c</li>
        </ol>
    </li>
</ol>
```

I attempted with [diff-match-patch](https://github.com/google/diff-match-patch), [html-differ](https://github.com/bem/html-differ) and [difflib](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/difflib.html) but all seems to read off HTML tags as plain text. In other words, tags like `<u>` and `/u><` were picked up as changed. Doing so will render these tags like any plain text when displaying on the front end.

My ideal outcome is to be capable of rendering something like so like google docs:
[image]

My stack is in nodejs and python3. Appreciate some advice, thanks.